# PostMessage only works during first ~110ms of application lifetime

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to send `Ctrl+Up` to a non-active Spotify window. Although this isn't a reliable method for every app, a `PostMessage` using `WM_KEYDOWN` / `WM_KEYUP` does work... but only if it's the very first thing my program does. After my own program has been running for more than 120 milliseconds, nothing happens.

With the repro below, Spotify does nothing in response.

If I *remove* the `Thread.Sleep` call at the top of the program, or lower its value below 100, then Spotify does change its volume in response to the simulated input.

With values between 100 and 120, then it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

What the heck is going on and how can I fix it?

Here's the self-contained repro:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // 0-100: Works reliably
        // 101-119: Works some of the time
        // 120+: Never works
        Thread.Sleep(120);
        var hWnd = Process.GetProcessesByName("spotify").Select(x => x.MainWindowHandle).FirstOrDefault(x => x != IntPtr.Zero);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 0);
    }

    public static readonly int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    public static readonly int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    public static readonly int WM_CHAR = 0x102;

    public static readonly int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    public static readonly int VK_UP = 0x26;
    public static readonly int VK_DOWN = 0x28;

    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "PostMessage")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, uint lParam);
}
```

Other observations:

- `PostMessage` always returns `1`
- The `hWnd` value is consistently correct
- I can send *multiple* rounds of `Ctrl-Up` during the "opening window" - putting the 4 `PostMessage` calls inside a `for` loop will correctly increment the volume multiple times
- Repro is a Console App but I also see the behavior in a WinForms application

Comment: Will this ever end? [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: I really doubt you've read the question if that's your reaction

Comment: I have, and the issue were moot, if you took the right course of action: UI Automation.

Comment: `PostMessage` isn't reliable for *all applications* as a characteristic of how each app handles inputs. For any given application, it's possible it does work. None of this answers the question of how it matters at all **how long my own program has been running** as to whether or not it works. At the very least there is something answer-worthy about why the amount of time I've slept at the top of the function *can possibly matter*.

Comment: One thing to note about the delay is that the Windows Clock is not as accurate as it is precise. And even if the time is properly measured, the CPU might not pick up that thread in time. Even that Thread.Sleep(1) could end up delaying the later function calls as much as 20 ms or more. Sleep is a minimum time of delay, not a accutrate time of delay. That would explain why 101-119 works sometimes - because sometiems you end up overshooting the window of opportunity. I can not really help with the whole "it matters after what much runtime I send it" issue.

Comment: If you do believe that this is answer-worthy, at least fix your P/Invoke declaration. `msg` is unsigned, `wParam` and `lParam` are pointer-sized, and the return value is an `int`. Since you aren't specifying a character encoding, the `EntryPoint` is also wrong.

Comment: For my use case I cannot change the active window, so techniques like `SendInput` are not applicable.

Comment: That's why I proposed UI Automation. It can operate on windows that aren't the foreground window.

Comment: I also have to point out that calling WinAPI and other unamanged code is not exactly teh ideal case for a C# forum. The .NET Designers went to great lenghts so you would never have to handle naked pointers. The moment you leave that area by calling unmanaged code (P/Invke in particular), C# programmers stop being able to help you fully. A native C++ Forum migt be a better place to ask. They handle this kind of stuff regularly.

Comment: @IInspectable "ui automation" is a bad search term; I keep finding docs for unrelated stuff or more PostMessage suggestions. Can you link to (any) relevant API?

Comment: @Christopher: Stack Overflow is neither a forum, nor is it C#-only. And the [tag:winapi] tag will attract exactly those people with domain knowledge required to help out.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Comment: @IInspectable This is tagged as C# winapi and pinvoke. Indeed the C# tag is the only reason I even **saw** this. Native C++ Programmers are a few times more likely to have encountered this.

Comment: Spotify doesn't expose any useful UI Automation patterns on its Volume slider so I'm back where I started

Comment: Inspect Spotifys messages with Spy++, if it gets the message after sleeping then the problem is with Spotify and if not, the problem is your app.

Comment: I believe Spotify has some sort of API but it is not free to access.